# my app was working good but now shows the error [Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance

Tags: javascript, react-native, iterable, unhandled-exception, unhandled-promise-rejection

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/19Q5j.png)and the source error is located in node_modules/Libraries/LogBox/Data/LogBoxData.js I don't now how to fix it
the code
/LogBoxData.js `export function addLog(log: LogData): void { const errorForStackTrace = new Error();`

please have you an idea

Comment: It is quite possiblle that a npm module you are using is expecting an array which it tries to spread but it gets undefined or something non-iterable instead. Try and check what part of your application uses that module and where it may pass a non-iterable value where it would expect an iterable one.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to see exactly reason, but It happens when you try to assign some variable (object/array) use spread syntax but the value is primitive data type.

for example:

```js
let x = []
let y = 1;

x = [...y]
```